# What could be the reason for a link not to appear in Windows 10 Start Menu?

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

I know I can open the Start Menu folder using the Run dialog along with `shell:Common Start Menu`. My program is listed there but is not shown in the Start Menu. I learnt, that duplicate targets are skipped but this is not the case. I regenerated the index also without any effect. Reboot did not change this neither. What could that be? There is no icon at the target, could this be the reason? It is a link to an uninstall.exe file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design. The Windows 10 Start Menu filters the shortcuts in your Start Menu folder using a certain set of rules before showing them on the Apps List. One of the rules, as you mentioned is that duplicate shortcuts are skipped. Another one is that all shortcuts to uninstalls are skipped, as they expect the uninstall function to be performed through settings.